# React Typescript: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

It is a React component to create a Check Box Button, I am having this error in setRSelected(1),setRSelected(2)...

```
  const [cSelected, setCSelected] = useState([]);
  const [rSelected, setRSelected] = useState();

  const onCheckboxBtnClick = (selected: never) => {
    const index = cSelected.indexOf(selected);
    if (index < 0) {
      cSelected.push(selected);
    } else {
      cSelected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setCSelected([...cSelected]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h5>Radio Buttons</h5>
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setRSelected(1)} active={rSelected === 1}>One</Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setRSelected(2)} active={rSelected === 2}>Two</Button>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setRSelected(3)} active={rSelected === 3}>Three</Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
      <p>Selected: {rSelected}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I get this error:
`Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.`

How can I fix this

Comment: You can also use `React.useState<number>()`. The type of `rSelected` will automatically be `number | undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare type when use `useState` like this:

```
const [rSelected, setRSelected] = useState<number | undefined>();
```